# How to cast box3d_extent to geometry (Rare problem with Geoserver and Postgis)

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I use Geoserver 2.1.3 and "POSTGIS="1.5.3" GEOS="3.2.2-CAPI-1.6.2" PROJ="Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009" LIBXML="2.7.6" USE_STATS" on PostgreSQL 9.1

From time to time (well - today I can't get around it anymore) I get the following error when I try to "calc native bounds from data" while creating a new layer in Geoserver.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Error occured calculating bounds at 
org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getBoundsInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:485) at 
org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureStore.getBoundsInternal(JDBCFeatureStore.java:179) at 
org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getBounds(ContentFeatureSource.java:370) at 
    ...
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error occured calculating bounds at 
    org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.getBounds(JDBCDataStore.java:1137) at 
    org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getBoundsInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:478) ... 
    94 more 
    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function st_envelope(box3d_extent) does not exist 
    No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 30
```

The geometry column contains points, the SRID is defined in the *geometry_columns* tables. And it worked before... Anyways.. I will upgrade to PostGIS2 in a few weeks.. For now I need help on how to transform a PostGIS **box3d_extent** to a **geometry**.

With that information I want to dirty-quick-fix this with the creation of a local hack-function **st_envelope(box3d_extent)** which would then call **st_envelope(geometry)**.

Thanks in advance for any answers helping with the cast- and/or base problem ;-)

Steve

Answer (score 1):

You are suffering from this bug I posted which is an issue with the upgrade script.

http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/223

Just create a cast as noted in the ticket.